# MPIO Issue With Server 2012 R2 iSCSI Target

Tags: load-balancing, windows-server-2012, iscsi, mpio

The Setup.

We just got 2 HP DL360 g6's Server 2012, running Hyper-V, server1 has an additional P800 controller for an MSA70 sas storage, and is hosting iscsi targets for hyper-v's on server 2.
both workstations use dedicated dual nics to connect to a SAN vlan, MPIO is installed on both servers. They also have a dedicated host NIC and dedicated NICs for most of the VMs.

The Good.

server2 connects to the target and recognizes the MPIO setup fairly quickly (configured with powershell). Watching the task manager i can see that server2 is using both NICs to deliver and receive data.

The Problem.

server1 is not, only the lowest ip NIC has any traffic at all.

On server1: Get-IscsiTargetServerSetting shows portals for all ip addresses, even the host NIC and ipv6. (can i stop some of those?) Get-MSDSMAutomaticClaimSettings returns iSCSI True. Get-MSDSMGlobalDefaultLoadBalancePolicy returns RR.

On server2: Get-IscsiConection shows entires for both Initiator Addresses. but only one Target Address ((i think this is my problem). but Get-IscsiTargetPortal shows Target Portal Address for both NICs on server1. (they don't have names... should they have names?)

where am i going wrong here?

Comment: well... i don't know why it wasn't working, went through all the documention, did what appears to be the same thing, but it works. it defiantly seems to have been the initiatior side because i didn't make any changes on the server1 side.

Comment: looking over my steps again i think it may have been because i did not run "mpclaim -n -i -a" before creating the connection on the initiator. hopefully that does someone some good.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the essential reason, but I can give you a white paper link for deploying Failover iSCSI SAN for 2012: http://www.kernsafe.com/white-papers/iscsi-san-for-windows-server-2012-cluster.aspx

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.